# Code to do Bilinear transformation not working

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I want to try this bilinear transformation of a rectangle to a quad described here
http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bilinearwarp/FourCornerImageWarp2.pdf
on page 4.

I have the square

```
(500,900)(599,900)(599,999)(500,999)
```

and the quad

```
(454,945)(558,951)(598,999)(499,999)
```

Where the ith entry of the quad and square coordinates above are corresponding corners.

With that in place, I can make the following matrices

`[1 500 900 450000][a0] [454]
[1 599 900 539100][a1]=[558]
[1 599 999 598401][a2] [598]
[1 500 999 499500][a3] [499]`

`[1 500 900 450000][b0] [945]
[1 599 900 539100][b1]=[951]
[1 599 999 598401][b2] [999]
[1 500 999 499500][b3] [999]`

If I solve for them I get

`a0=-709.911845730028
a1=1.50964187327824
a2=0.709621467197225
a3=-0.000510152025303541
b0=148.305785123967 
b1=0.611570247933884 
b2=0.85154576063667 
b3=-0.000612182430364249`

But then when I run this python script (I want to simulate manually, converting the point (454, 945) on the quad to the point (500,900) on the square), I get a different answer. I get (442.90822654, 1024.0)...

```
X = 454
Y = 945

a0=-709.911845730028
a1=1.50964187327824
a2=0.709621467197225
a3=-0.000510152025303541


b0=148.305785123967 
b1=0.611570247933884 
b2=0.85154576063667 
b3=-0.000612182430364249

A = b2*a3 - b3*a2
C_one = (b0*a1 - b1*a0)
C = C_one + (b1*X - a1*Y)
B_one = (b0*a3 - b3*a0) + (b2*a1 - b1*a2)
B = B_one + (b3*X - a3*Y)

V = (-B + (B*B - 4*A*C)**0.5 ) / (2*A)
U = (X - a0 - a2*V) / (a1 + a3*V)

print U,V
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your linear algebra notation correctly, then i disagree with your `a` and `b`:

```
sage: A = Matrix([[1,500,900,450000],[1, 599, 900, 539100],
                  [1, 599, 999 ,5984],[1, 500, 999, 499500]])
sage: v = vector([945, 951, 999, 999])
sage: w = vector([454, 558, 598, 499])
sage: a = A.solve_right(w)
sage: b = A.solve_right(v)
sage: print(a); print(N(a))
(-3435371408/7209873, 15036641/14419746, 721395/1602194, 5/582616)
(-476.481542462676, 1.04278126674353, 0.450254463566834, 8.58198195724113e-6)
sage: print(b); print(N(b))
(1029623095/2403291, 123379/2403291, 432837/801097, 3/291308)
(428.422149044789, 0.0513375200922402, 0.540305356280201, 0.0000102983783486894)
sage: 
sage: A * a
(454, 558, 598, 499)
sage: A * b
(945, 951, 999, 999)
```

calculating

```
from math import sqrt

X = 454
Y = 945

a = (-476.481542462676, 1.04278126674353,
     0.450254463566834, 8.58198195724113e-6)

b = (428.422149044789, 0.0513375200922402,
     0.540305356280201, 0.0000102983783486894)

A = b[2]*a[3] - b[3]*a[2]
C_one = (b[0]*a[1] - b[1]*a[0])
C = C_one + (b[1]*X - a[1]*Y)
B_one = (b[0]*a[3] - b[3]*a[0]) + (b[2]*a[1] - b[1]*a[2])
B = B_one + (b[3]*X - a[3]*Y)
V = (-B + sqrt((pow(B,2) - 4*A*C))) / (2*A)
U = (X - a[0] - a[2]*V) / (a[1] + a[3]*V)

print( U,V )
```

i get

```
892.3074973991894 -0.0
```

that's different... don't know if it is correct.

Comment: No it should be 500,900 as I stated in my post.

Comment: sorry, did not find that the first time... i briefly looked over it again... shouldn't you construct the matrix from the quad and  the rhs of your equation from the square and then solve for a and b? i still did not get the correct result that way; for comparision: new a would be `a=(833.5, 1, -0.833, 0)`.
`

Comment: I tried to follow exactly the stuff from the PDF article.

Comment: sorry, was on the wrong page; what i said is for equations 2a), 2b). but you are at 3a), 3b), right?